# Shell script for reading the response from curl and looping on a particular value from the JSON response

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a shell script(.sh) and trying to read a particular value from the JSON response from a REST call. Below is the sample json response which I get by calling a Rest URL(GET)

```
{"isTestRunning":false,"status":null}
```

Here is the logic I am trying to code in shell script. I am completely new to the shell scripting and finding it difficult to script for my requirement.
How do I have to start on this? If anyone of you have a documentation link will also be very helpful?

```
response = curl 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable'
for(till response.isTestRunning is true)
{
  response = curl 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable'
   if(response.isTestRunning is false){
    //curl 'another url'
    //break the loop.
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for that. `jq` is like sed for JSON data.

```bash
while [ "$(curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable' |
           jq '.isTestRunning')" = "true" ]; do
  sleep 10
done
curl 'ANOTHER_URL'
```

If `jq` isn't available you can use the following, somewhat ugly regular expression with `sed` instead.

```bash
while [ "$(curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable' |
           sed -re 's/.*":(false|true),".*/\1/')" = "true" ]; do
  sleep 10
done
curl 'ANOTHER_URL'
```

BTW: If you can create shell scripts, then you can install `jq`, it's just a single binary.

Comment: Thank you @JGK for the prompt response! We do not have the privilege to install jq. Is there any other way to parse json  in shell script or in the curl command itself?

Comment: Enhanced the answer without the use of `jq`

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame you can't install `jq`, because it really is the best way to deal with JSON from the shell. @JGK's `sed` solution works as long as `isTestRunning` is the only boolean in the object returned by the `curl`; if that changes, you can complicate the `sed` expression a little to make sure that you get the right one, but using regexes to parse JSON quickly gets unruly.

There may be other options depending on what's installed on your system. Python usually ships with its JSON module, for example:

```
isTestRunning() { 
  curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable' |
    python -c 'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["isTestRunning"])' |
    grep -q True
}

while isTestRunning; do 
  sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JGK the below one worked for me like a magic. Thanks a lot @JGK !

```
while [ "$(curl -sS -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://test-url/checkTestEnable' |
           sed -re 's/.*":(false|true),".*/\1/')" = "true" ]; do
  sleep 10
done
curl 'ANOTHER_URL'
```